# Filamentphp keyValue field not storing or fetching json correctly

Tags: php, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am trying to make use of filaments KeyValue field, but I must surely be missing something as the storing or fetching of the json data is not displaying in the field as expected. Please see the attached image.

My Migration
`$table->json('fields')->nullable();`

My Model

```
    protected $cast = [
        'fields' => 'json'
    ];
```

My Field in the Resource class

```
    Forms\Components\Section::make('Dynamic Fields')
    ->schema([
        Forms\Components\KeyValue::make('fields')
            ->keyLabel('Field name')
            ->valueLabel('Field value')
            ->reorderable(),
    ]),
```

What am I missing? Please help.

[Displaying of data in KeyValue field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tzsZ.png)

1. I tried changing the field type to text and casting the field to array and to json and still had the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Found my issue.
Spelling mistake in the model, used cast instead of casts.

```
protected $casts = [
    'fields' => 'json'
];
```